# Catch Youtube video in Wordpress post and insert into custom field value

Tags: php, wordpress, video, youtube

Could anyone help me out, I need to scan the post for a youtube video. If the post contains a video (`www.youtube.com/embed/youtubepostid`) then I'd like to copy that url into a custom field with the key **"iFrame"**.

I'm going round in circles looking for an answer and whenever I try soething I get up with the WSD :(

Any pointers in the right direction?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question.  What have *you* tried so far?  What were the results?

Comment: you need a bit more logic to this. str_pos will return the string position of the string www.youtube.com, you can then find the next blank space and then substr it out. But this is a weak logic. Where is the url saved? can you hook a function or change it to save into post_meta, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have coded something to solve our common problem ;)
I have added something too if you to display your formatted embed video whatever you want (out of the post content).

**I - Add these functions to your 'functions.php' file**

**1- Remove the youtube embed from content**

```
function remove_video( $content ) {
    $postOutput = preg_replace('/<iframe[^>]+./','', $content);
    return $postOutput;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_video', 100 );
```

**2 - Catch and return the youtube embed from content**

```
function catch_first_youtube_video() {
    global $post, $posts;
    // Catch youtube iframe src
    preg_match_all('/(http|https).*(yout).*/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    $youtubeUrl = $matches[0][0];

    // Set the new meta for your post.
    add_post_meta($post->ID, 'iFrame',  $youtubeUrl)  

    // Remove http: or https:
    $formated = preg_replace('/(http:|https:|watch\\?v=)/i','', $youtubeUrl);

    // Formated string '//youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXX'
    $formated =str_replace('youtube.com/','youtube.com/embed/', $formated );

    return '<iframe src="'.$formated .'"></iframe>';
}
```

**II - Call those functions in your post template content**

**1 - Show the post's content in your post template without the embed video**

```
remove_filter(the_content(),'remove_video', 100 );
```

**2 - Show the embed video iframe whatever you want to !**

```
<?= catch_first_youtube_video(); ?>
```

And voilà ! Enjoy ! (Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1):

I try to implemented but get one Warning and one Notice.

1. in the line `add_post_meta($post->ID, 'iFrame',  $youtubeUrl);`needs a ; to close. With that I fix the warning.
2. "**Notice:** Undefined offset: 0 in `$youtubeUrl = $matches[0][0];` and I don´t know how to fix it :(

Thanx for any help.